# Area code is not set - Magento 2.4.3-p1

Tags: magento2

I'm installing a new third party extension in a new fresh magento 2.4.3-p1 environment with php 7.4

after uploading the module , and running :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I ended up with the following error:

```
    Enabling caches:
Current status:
layout: 1
block_html: 1
full_page: 1
Area code is not set
```

all other third party module are installed successfully,

Comment: It looks like third party module's fault. Can you paste the name of the module?

Comment: Does that module have some console command? If it does show that code here.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrauze Hi
yes , the third party moduleit is Advanced Booking system from Webkul

Comment: @MansourWbss Try to run `php bin/magento cache:flush` before. But supposing everything is ok with your cache then it looks like there is some method that is run in the "import" phase of `setup:updgrade` or any constructor (elsewhere in the application) that is using `getAreaCode()`. This method throws an exception if the area code is not set and in fact it is not set in setup:upgrade. Try to install 3rd party modules in some other order on fresh magento to find out which module delivered you this failing code. You can also search for this method in installed 3rd party modules.

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzKrauze
yes, running  php bin/magento cache:flush  shows everything is okay 

I have installed it to a fresh magento2.4.3 , and still facing the same
I can not find the method in the 3rd party module